# Ruby apns gem returns nil

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to get the APNS gem to work with my Rails app. I had originally set this up several months ago, and push notifications to iOS devices worked swimmingly. Now, my app is live and I've found that notifications aren't going out anymore. The [APNS gem](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS) hasn't been updated in some time, so I've tried various later forks of it, all to the same effect.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
APNS.host = 'gateway.push.apple.com' 
APNS.pem  = Rails.root + "lib/push_production.pem"
APNS.port = 2195 
APNS.send_notification(device_token, "Test send" )
```

And the result?

```
=> nil
```

There's no feedback from any method, no logfile that I can check. I've tried generating and regenerating my certificate; everything seems okay there. I've tried expressing my device token in various ways, without the angle brackets, without spaces between groups of characters... APNS don't care.

Given the number of moving parts involved in this, I know this is a tough question. But can anyone suggest where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've found the answer. After registering an account with Urban Airship, I tried sending a test message to my phone, and again to no avail. But these guys actually have their act together, so they were able to show me the error message! Turns out my device token was invalid. Why? Because it was generated by the sandboxed version of the app.

Yes, my app is in the store, but it turns out that my App Store distribution profile was generated before the push notification entitlement was added to it. So when you run the codesign tool on my executable, it doesn't show the entitlement. Here's an example:

```
Diomedes:Release-iphoneos aaron$ codesign -dvvvv --entitlements - Tiberius.app
```

That command should show a plist that contains the  key with a value of "production". My release didn't have that key at all.

I was actually forced to generate an all-new distribution profile in the Provisioning Portal, which finally did include the correct entitlements. I haven't been able to test this yet (8 day App Store review, anyone?) but I feel like this is the problem.

P.S. [This article](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/71836-rejected-device-tokens) on Urban Airship's site was instrumental in helping me.

Answer (score 2):

The [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1) says this :

> If you send a notification and APNs finds the notification malformed
>   or otherwise unintelligible, it returns an error-response packet prior
>   to disconnecting. **(If there is no error, APNs doesn’t return
>   anything.)** Figure 5-3 depicts the format of the error-response packet.

So it only makes sense that the gem doesn't return anything, because Apple's server doesn't let it know what it's doing. Also if you look at the gem's github page, the given examples do not handle the return value of `APNS.send_notification`.

Last time I worked with Apple Push Notifications, it pretty much behaved like a black box, not returning anything most of the time.

Comment: I've noted the same shortcomings. Is there a solution to this problem? Any way to get the return error value?

Comment: Well you could try to override the gem's `send_notifications` method, and try accessing the `ssl` variable in it to see what you can get from it (see [the code on github](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS/blob/master/lib/apns/core.rb)).
But like said before since APNS doesn't return anything if (supposedly) successfull, there's not much you can do I'm afraid.
`ssl.write` will only give you the number of bytes written so that might not be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
Is your sandbox value correct? Use false for production certificates and use true for development certificates.
```

P. S. https://github.com/tompesman/push-core/issues/27